# Finding Starting Parameters in R for Exponential Models

Tags: r, modeling, exponential

I'm working to build some models in R and am having trouble not returning the error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

For reference, my dataset and the code I am trying is:

```
x <- c(1:7)
y <- c(21, 27, 26, 33, 52, 68, 96)
fit8 <- nls(y ~ a*exp(b*x), data=base, start=list(a=16, b = .22))
```

Where the starting values were found in Excel, but I still return the same error when using them in R.

In general, are there easy ways to loop through unknown starting values to avoid the error? I need to create a systemic way to determine the best fit lines for ~1,000 different datasets within a larger dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code without data=base, I get the output as expected. Is it possible you have assigned other values to a data frame called base?

```
nls(y ~ a*exp(b*x), start=list(a=16, b=.22))
```

It returns the output as expected:

```
Nonlinear regression model
model: y ~ a * exp(b * x)
...
  a       b 
11.8560  0.2953 
...
```

Comment: Yes, I had base defined as a dataframe consisting of x, y, and another variable (say z). Suggestions on when to use defining the data field vs. not?

Comment: Fine to do either, just a potential source of error if you post a reproducible example on SO (i.e. the code you posted could not run). If you run your first two lines, and my code, does it run?